# Please help me to solve this route errors

Tags: php, laravel

Route

```
Route::get('board/{category}', ['as' => 'board.showByCate', 'uses' =>'BoardController@showByCate']);
```

Controller

```
public function cate() {

    $categories = category::all();

    return view('welcome', compact('categories'));

}

public function showByCate($category) {

    $boards = board::where('category', '=', $category)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(3)->get();

    $allBoards = board::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(3);

    return view('board.index', compact('boards', 'allBoards'));

}
```

View

```
       <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('board.showByCate') }}">all</a>
                    </li>
                    @foreach($categories as $category)
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ route('board.showByCate', $category->category) }}">
                                {{$category->category}}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
```

this codes bring errors..
1/2
UrlGenerationException in UrlGenerationException.php line 17:
Missing required parameters for [Route: board.showByCate] [URI: board/{category}].
2/2
ErrorException in UrlGenerationException.php line 17:
Missing required parameters for [Route: board.showByCate] [URI: board/{category}]. (View: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)

how can I solve this error//

Comment: You can modify the title to better represent your problem. Remember, it is a question someone else can have in the future so they better have a chance to find it.

Comment: In your view concat the $category->category  to the route. `{{route('board.showByCate.'. $category->category)}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to build URL with `route('board.showByCate')`, but you route has `{category}` parameter.

So, you need to pass this parameter with [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-route):

```
route('board.showByCate', ['category' => 'someCategory'])
```

Or you could [make parameter optional](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#parameters-optional-parameters):

```
Route::get('board/{category?}', ....
```